# [Resolvido]Atribuir valor da label ao selecionar o produto na combobox

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia,

Eu tenho este formulário onde nas comboboxes já aparecem os valores pretendidos:
[![Fromulário][1]][1]

Agora tenho um problema, porque eu ao selecionar o produto, quero que apareça na label "Unidade" automaticamente a unidade do produto.

Este é o código que usei para preencher a combobox "Produto":

```
<form name="Registo" action="conexao.php" method="POST">
<b>Produtos:</b>
<br>
<select name="select_Produtos">
<option>Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_Produtos = "SELECT * FROM Produtos";
$resultado_Produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_Produtos);
while($row_Produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_Produtos)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Produtos['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Produtos['Product']; ?>
</option> <?php
}
?>
</select><br>
```

E agora é o código do resto do formulario:

```
<b>Unidade:</b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="TipoUnid" size="20"><br>
    <b>Quantidade:</b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Amount" size="5"><br>
<b>Observações (Opcional):</b>
<br>
 <textarea name="Comments" cols="30" rows="5"> </textarea><br>
<b>Quarto (Opcional):</b>
<br>
<select name="select_Bedroom">
<option>Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_Quarto = "SELECT * FROM Quarto";
$resultado_Quarto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_Quarto);
 while($row_Quarto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_Quarto)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Quarto['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Quarto['Bedroom']; ?>
</option> <?php
}
?>
</select><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="adicionar" value="Adicionar">
</form>
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
CREATE TABLE `Estado` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IDProd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Quarto` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Bedroom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `Unidades` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Registo` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RegistrationDate` date NOT NULL,
  `IDProd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IDUnid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TipoUnid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Badroom` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1530 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Produtos` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `IDDesc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Bom dia, continuo sem conseguir resolver o meu problema, alguém poderá ajudar?

Deixo aqui o link que me permitiu resolver esta situação:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9RXHMn57Gk][2]

Mas mesmo resolvendo a situação com este video, agradeço a disponibilidade da parte da comunidade por me terem dado dicas importantes para chegar à solução

Comment: E o que o valor da unidade e de onde vem ele?

Comment: o valor da unidade vem da base de dados mysql. A query da combobox produto vem da tabela produtos e só tem os campos id e product e a unidade vem da tabela tipoUnid e tem os campos id, unidade e idprod que é igual ao id do produto.

Comment: terás de usar `jquery` com `ajax` para fazer isso

Comment: E será que pode colocar um exemplo para eu tentar fazer? É a primeira vez que estou a fazer isto

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza você irá precisar implementar a solução com JavaScript, mas o uso do AJAX é desnecessário. Você não precisa fazer mais uma requisição ao servidor para obter apenas um valor que você já conhece inicialmente. A solução mais fácil que eu vejo nesta situação é armazenar o respectivo valor da unidade em um atributo `data` da opção e buscá-lo com JavaScript ao selecionar determinado valor.

Por exemplo, o HTML gerado atualmente pelo seu código é algo como:

```
<select name="select_Bedroom" id="select_Bedroom">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Quarto 1</option>
    <option value="2">Quarto 2</option>
    <option value="3">Quarto 3</option>
</select>
```

Vamos supor que a descrição do quarto 1 é `x`, do quarto 2 é `y` e do quarto 3 é `z`, então o que você pode fazer é criar o seguinte HTML:

```
<select name="select_Bedroom" id="select_Bedroom">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1" data-desc="x">Quarto 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-desc="y">Quarto 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-desc="z">Quarto 3</option>
</select>
```

Perceba a definição do atributo `data-desc` com os respectivos valores nos elementos `option`. Isso você consegue definir com o próprio PHP:

```
<option value="<?=$row_Quarto['ID']; ?>" data-desc="<?= $row_Quarto['Description'] ?>"><?=$row_Quarto['Bedroom']; ?></option>
```

Com JavaScript, então, você pode tratar o evento `change` do elemento `select`, recuperar a opção selecionada e verificar o valor do atributo `data-desc`. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
// Objeto para manipulação do DOM:
const select = document.getElementById("select_Bedroom");

// Atribui a função ao evento `change`:
select.addEventListener("change", function (event) {

    // Seleciona a opção selecionada:
    let selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

    // Exibe o valor de `data-desc` da opção selecionada:
    console.log("A unidade da opção selecionada é: " + selectedOption.dataset.desc);
});
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando:

```js
// Objeto para manipulação do DOM:
const select = document.getElementById("select_Bedroom");

// Atribui a função ao evento `change`:
select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  // Seleciona a opção selecionada:
  let selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

  // Exibe o valor de `data-unidade` da opção selecionada:
  console.log("A unidade da opção selecionada é: " + selectedOption.dataset.desc);
});
```

```html
<select name="select_Bedroom" id="select_Bedroom">
  <option>Selecione</option>
  <option value="1" data-desc="x">Quarto 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-desc="y">Quarto 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-desc="z">Quarto 3</option>
</select>
```

Desta forma, basta você alimentar o outro campo do formulário com o valor obtido e isso pode ser feito através de JavaScript também.

```js
// Objeto para manipulação do DOM:
const select = document.getElementById("select_Bedroom");
const unidade = document.getElementById("unidade");

// Atribui a função ao evento `change`:
select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  // Seleciona a opção selecionada:
  let selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

  // Define o valor da unidade como sendo `data-desc`:
  unidade.value = selectedOption.dataset.desc;
});
```

```html
<select name="select_Bedroom" id="select_Bedroom">
  <option>Selecione</option>
  <option value="1" data-desc="x">Quarto 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-desc="y">Quarto 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-desc="z">Quarto 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="unidade" />
```

Comment: Mas sendo assim vou ter que fazer isto:

<option value="1" data-unidade="x">Quarto 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-unidade="y">Quarto 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-unidade="z">Quarto 3</option>

para cada um dos produtos?

Comment: Eu comentei sobre como fazer o PHP, ficou alguma dúvida nisso? Não entendi o que seriam esses `produtos`.

Comment: Neste momento estou totalmente perdido, não estou a conseguir nada

Comment: Alguma parte da resposta você não conseguiu entender?

Comment: está um pouco confuso, código salteado, nem sei onde o aplicar. É o segundo dia que estou a mexer em php......mas queria muito resolver este problema. se pudesses enviar um exemplo direito para o poder aplicar e perceber ficava te muito grato amigo

Comment: Qual é a coluna que possui o valor da unidade?

Comment: eu tenho a tabela produtos que tem as colunas: id (que é o id do produto), Product, IDDesc (que é o id da unidade) e Description (descrição da unidade). 
No meu formulário já tenho a combobox produto a receber o nome de cada produto para selecionar, e ao selecionar queria que a label a seguir  da Unidade assumisse logo o valor da coluna description  (que é a descrição da unidade).
Deu para entender?

Comment: @Bruno dei uma pequena editada, veja se ajudou em algo, se não, tente descrever quais partes ficou difícil entender que tento melhorar.

Comment: Tenho que usar os dois códigos ou só a segunda parte do código? Se tenho de utilizar a primeira parte onde o aplico?

Comment: Todos os códigos HTML que utilizei na resposta são exemplos para criar uma resposta verificável. Você deve adaptar para o seu problema utilizando o código PHP que citei. Você já fez um `while` para exibir as opções, basta adicionar o atributo `data-desc` como descrevi. O código JavaScript, sim, você precisará incorporar na sua aplicação basicamente da maneira que está ou adaptando conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Anderson Carlos woss, encontras te presente para me ajudares?

Comment: Anderson, não estou a conseguir resolver a outra situação, pode colocar um link a exemplicar este exemplo que me deu para o poder colocar em prática?

Answer (score -1):

> O Formulário

```
<form name="Registo" action="conexao.php" method="POST">
<b>Produtos:</b>
<br>
<select name="select_Produtos" id="select_Produtos">
<option>Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_Produtos = "SELECT * FROM Produtos";
$resultado_Produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_Produtos);
while($row_Produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_Produtos)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Produtos['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Produtos['Product']; ?>
</option> <?php
}
?>
</select><br>
<b>Unidade:</b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="TipoUnid" id="TipoUnid" size="20"><br>
    <b>Quantidade:</b>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Amount" size="5"><br>
<b>Observações (Opcional):</b>
<br>
 <textarea name="Comments" cols="30" rows="5"> </textarea><br>
<b>Quarto (Opcional):</b>
<br>
<select name="select_Bedroom">
<option>Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_Quarto = "SELECT * FROM Quarto";
$resultado_Quarto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_Quarto);
 while($row_Quarto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_Quarto)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Quarto['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Quarto['Bedroom']; ?>
</option> <?php
}
?>
</select><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="adicionar" value="Adicionar">
</form>
```

> Jquery + ajax

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select_Produtos").bind('load change',function() {
        var IDProduto= $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'dropAmount.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache:false,
            data: {IDProduto: IDProduto},
            async: false,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function(data) {
        $("#TipoUnid").html(data);                                                                   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

        });
        });      
    </script>
```

> dropAmount.php

```
     <?php
      include('conetar.php'); 
      if(isset($_POST['IDProduto'])){
       $IDProduto= $_POST['IDProduto'];
       $query= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Unidades.Description FROM Produtos RIGHT JOIN Unidades ON Unidades.ID = Produtos.IDDesc where produtos.ID=$IDProduto");
       while($getDescription = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $Description=$getUnidade['Description'];
        echo '<input type="text" name="TipoUnid" size="5" value="'.$Description.'"><br>';
        }
    ?>
```

Nota: Não se esqueça de colocar os `IDs` no input e no select.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63631/discussion-on-answer-by-djva-resolvidoatribuir-valor-da-label-ao-selecionar-o)